# Dell m2800 Hardware radio switch off

Tags: dell

I've seem to have turned off.  How to I toggle it back on.  Read Fn+f2 for earlier dells. Not working on mine

Comment: Did wireless work before with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The wireless switch is located on the right side of the unit.  Make sure its turned on.  See image below

[image]